# Issue with value count in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset containing football data and I would like to figure something out.
The dataset contains data from a lot of games, and for every game, all the players in the club is mentioned in a column in the format of list. I would like to find out how I can get an output like this

```
Player     clubs
    Tom     3 
    Car     2 
    Jon     2
    Tex     1
```

etc.

This is the code I have tried for it, but i get an error: `unhashable type: Series`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'club': ['Bath', 'Bath', 'Bristol', 'Bristol', 'Bristol', 'Swindon'], 
                   'Players': [[ 'Tom', 'Jon', 'Tex'],[ 'Tom', 'Jon', 'Tex'],[ 'Car', 'Snow', 'Tom'], [ 'Car', 'Snow', 'Tom'], [ 'Car', 'Snow', 'Tom'], [ 'Tom',  'Car',  'Jon']]})

tr = df.groupby('club')
trt = pd.Series([bg for bgs in tr.players_as_list for bg in bgs])
trt.value_counts()
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example of your problem

Comment: Please see [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with sample input and expected output

Comment: All sorted. Apologies

Answer (score 2):

As you have a Series of list, it will be slow to use `explode` and `drop_duplicates`.

Here pure python should be more efficient:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(set)
for c, l in zip(df['club'], df['Players']):
    for k in l:
        d[k].add(c)
out = pd.Series({k: len(s) for k,s in d.items()}).sort_values(ascending=False)
```

output:

```
Tom     3
Jon     2
Car     2
Tex     1
Snow    1
dtype: int64
```

comparison on 600K rows:

```
# explode + groupby
605 ms ± 20.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# explode + value_counts
476 ms ± 17.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# pure python
259 ms ± 5.47 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: You are right. Standard python is more efficient!!! (but it's not very elegant :P)

Comment: @Corralien Define elegant? I think it is as elegant as the pandas solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try explode the `Players` column then count the unique values of `club` column in each group

```py
df = (df.explode('Players')
      .groupby('Players')['club'].nunique()
      .to_frame('clubs').reset_index())

# or

df = (df.explode('Players').drop_duplicates(['Players', 'club'])
      .groupby('Players')['club'].count()
      .to_frame('clubs').reset_index())

# or

df = (df.explode('Players')
      .groupby('Players')['club'].unique().apply(len)
      .to_frame('clubs').reset_index())
```

```
print(df)

  Players  clubs
0     Car      2
1     Jon      2
2    Snow      1
3     Tex      1
4     Tom      3
```

Comment: How could I order this by the number of clubs?

Comment: @sqlbik Just add `.sort_values('clubs', ascending=False)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `value_counts` instead of `groupby` after `explode` your dataframe:

```
out = (df.explode('Players').drop_duplicates(['Players', 'club'])
         .value_counts('Players').rename('clubs').reset_index())
print(out)

# Output
  Players  clubs
0     Tom      3
1     Car      2
2     Jon      2
3    Snow      1
4     Tex      1
```